# How to store,sort integers in a List (input from users)?

Tags: c#

Just trying to sort out int user inputs (eg 2,21,1 etc)with no luck!
What I am doing wrong?

```
        Console.WriteLine("Could you please insert a few numbers?");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        var numbers = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in input.Split(','))
        {
            numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item));
            numbers.Sort();
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Define *"no luck"* - what problem are you having with this code?

Comment: You should not be sorting the numbers inside the loop. The loop should just add the numbers to the list, then sort, then create a second loop to iterate through the sorted numbers and print them.

Comment: @itsme86 Thank you so much ,It worked!

Comment: You can use LINQ to sort as well like "numbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => x).ToList()" make sure to add "using System.LINQ;" to the top of the file

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to input, then sort, and then display.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Could you please insert a few numbers?");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        var numbers = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in input.Split(','))
        {
            numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item));
        }

        numbers.Sort();

        foreach (int item in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```